# Concatenate string in iOS without duplicate items

Tags: ios, string, append

I want to append multiple strings together in a loop but it keeps on adding the same data more than once.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i <colorsArray.count ; i++)
{
    TheColor * color1 = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if([color1.isSelected isEqualToString: @"YES"])
    {
        if ([colorsString isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            colorsString = color1.colorName;
        }
        else
        {
            colorsString =   [colorsString stringByAppendingFormat:@",%@",color1.colorName];
            NSLog(@"Color name %@",colorsString);
        }
    }
}
```

The result 1st time : red
The result 2nd time : red , red , yellow
The result 3rf time : red , red , yellow , purple

Comment: You don't NSLog the colorsString when the *first* color is added (`colorsString = color1.colorName;`). Could it be that the array simply contains two selected colors which are named "red". - Did you try to set a breakpoint in your method, single-step the code and inspect what happens?

Comment: Where is the declaration of `colorsString`? What is the class of `TheColor`?

Comment: @MartinR i printed colorsString= color1.colorName and each time it gets me different value

Comment: @user1286300: The answer is simple: Set a *breakpoint* in your method. Single-step through your code. Inspect the variables. Then you will find your problem quickly.

Comment: @Zaph colorsString is declared in this method first time, and TheColor is a class that is inherited from NSObject

Comment: @Zaph in this code colorString is never `declared` and doesn't matter where is TheColor class and the initialization..the problem is simply that he don't clean the string......i know.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you dont clean the string each time, and so you append data to the previous code. In any case, i write the best code for you because your is a little bit redundant:

```
colorsString = @"";
for(int i = 0 ; i <colorsArray.count ; i++)
{
    TheColor * color1 = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if([color1.isSelected isEqualToString: @"YES"])
    {
        colorsString = [colorsString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", ([colorsString isEqualToString:@""]) ? @"" : @",", color1.colorName];

        NSLog(@"Color name %@",colorsString);
    }
}
```

But we can optimize the code again: if the color selected is **EACH TIME 1**, and so you haven't multiple selected color, **you can exit from the for cycle** when you find that color:

```
colorsString = @"";
for(int i = 0 ; i <colorsArray.count ; i++)
{
    TheColor * color1 = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if([color1.isSelected isEqualToString: @"YES"])
    {
        colorsString = [colorsString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", ([colorsString isEqualToString:@""]) ? @"" : @",", color1.colorName];

        NSLog(@"Color name %@",colorsString);

        break;
    }
}
```

Another thing: THIS: `[color1.isSelected isEqualToString: @"YES"]` ...tell me **WHY**?

You must have a `BOOL` `@property` in your `TheColor` class and not a string. So replace the property with this:

```
@property (assign, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;
```

Then in your code you can simply do:

```
if(color1.isSelected)
```

and so here the final code:

```
colorsString = @"";
for(int i = 0 ; i <colorsArray.count ; i++)
{
    TheColor * color1 = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if(color1.isSelected)
    {
        colorsString = [colorsString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", ([colorsString isEqualToString:@""]) ? @"" : @",", color1.colorName];

        NSLog(@"Color name %@",colorsString);

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , yes the problem was that i didn't clear the colorsString.

Comment: Yes but i wrote also another improvement, read ad implement this. Moreover, your problem was really simple, take some minutes to to have some test manually and understand what is happening in your code.

Comment: ok , i took a lot of time in it and i know it was simple but i think i was doing it the wrong way regarding the debugging.i put the breakpoint inside the for loop not outside it. and yes of course using boolean is better than strings.